# Collaborative (Selfhosted?)-Web tool to edit big 2D tables

Tags: web-apps, table

I'm searching for a tool to support team in generating and editing a big 2D table.

Featured required:

- Web based interface to edit 2D table
- Self hosting prefered.
- Multi User
- Suitable for large tables: eg. 30 rows, 200 columns
- Content of Cells can be: integer, real, free text,..
- Version control: all Changes to be tracked. Logs of all changes includes (date, Username, old/new value, optional: Add note to each commitment) shall be possible to filter for: full table, certain cells, and/or certain columns.
- Export of full dataset to file: eg. CVS, .xlsx
- API to access data from other apps (eg. REST, SQL, ..)
- Lightweight, and easy usage.
- copy&paste of multiple cells from and to Excel should work.

Nice to have:

- Allow Groupping of Column headers.
- Different predefinded views of table: (columns/rows shown/hide)
- different user privilegues (eg. Admin to add remove columns, User just to edit content)
- simple formulars (e.g. sum of columns)
- Other collaborate functions: eg. commenting function
- Sorting and filtering function
- Range checking of Values
- support of single sign-in solutions in company environment

Tools, which I consider not suitable:

- Confluence: Not helpful at big tables. Limited export function
- Google docs, ONLYOFFICE etc, and similar tools: Version history & API not sufficient.
- [www.rowshare.com](http://www.rowshare.com): this is close to what I search. However it seems to be designed for smaller number of columns. With bigger tables the excel import was not working fine. Additionally I couldn't find an API. No easy access to version log.
- https://airtable.com/ works slightly better than rowshare. However I couldn't find a version history. There seem to be some software interfaces for workflows. Grouping of rows was not working. Seems a bit overloaded with features.
- https://telltable-s.sourceforge.net/ seems to be unmaintained since 2004.